# How to make last login on FOSUerBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am thinking to record last login in user table.

My assumption is like this .

1)make $lastLogin column in Entity.

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */

private $lastLogin;
```

2) update this data every time user logs-in

then ,,,How can I update this every time user logs-in?

What event or functions are driven when user login ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nothing. The FOSUserBundle base class has already a `getLastLogin()` method in which gets you the last login time as a `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly the authentication is managed by the SecurityBundle of symfony.

The event that occurs after a user is logged in is INTERACTIVE_LOGIN (security.interactive_login).

So you need to create a new [listener/subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) which will listen to this event.

Comment: Thank ,In this problem ,I can make solution by @Pazi's way though, your advice could be used in another situation.